# Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state

Tags: mysql, node.js, cron

Why am I getting this error? How do I solve this? I am trying to update the status column in my database using Node-cron. Also, I have another question, can I use another method to update the status column automatically without any interval or trigger? To reduce the performance affected on the server.

```
const db = require("../config/databaseConfig");
const cron = require("node-cron");

function updateStatus(callback) {
  var dbConn = db.getConnection();

  // Connect to the database
  dbConn.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    // Get the current date
    const currentDate = new Date();
    // Select all events from the 'events' table where the start date is before the current date and the end date is after the current date
    dbConn.query(
      "SELECT * FROM practiceme.events WHERE eventStart < ? AND eventEnd > ?",
      [currentDate, currentDate],
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) return callback(error, null);

        // For each row in the results, update the status of the event to 'ongoing'
        results.forEach((row) => {
          dbConn.query(
            'UPDATE practiceme.events SET status = "ongoing" WHERE eventId = ?',
            [row.id],
            (error) => {
              if (error) return callback(error, null);
            }
          );
        });
      }
    );
  });
}

function updateStatus2(callback) {
  var dbConn = db.getConnection();
  dbConn.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // Return an error if there was a problem connecting to the database
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    // Get the current date
    const currentDate = new Date();
    // Select all events from the 'events' table where the end date is before the current date
    dbConn.query(
      "SELECT * FROM practiceme.events WHERE eventEnd < ?",
      [currentDate],
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) return callback(error, null);

        // For each row in the results, update the status of the event to 'past'
        results.forEach((row) => {
          dbConn.query(
            'UPDATE practiceme.events SET status = "past" WHERE eventId = ?',
            [row.id],
            (error) => {
              if (error) return callback(error, null);
            }
          );
        });
      }
    );
    // Close the connection to the database
    dbConn.end();
  });
}

// Run the 'updateStatus' function every minute using the cron library
cron.schedule("* * * * *", () => {
  console.log("Updating status column every minute.");
  updateStatus((error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error updating status column:", error);
    } else {
      console.log("Status column updated successfully.");
    }
  });

  updateStatus2((error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error updating status column:", error);
    } else {
      console.log("Status column updated successfully.");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the connection after the callbacks have been executed, otherwise, the `dbConn.end()` line will be executed prior to the queries.
Try to move the `dbConn` variable in the `schedule` and pass it as a parameter:

```
const db = require('../config/databaseConfig');
const cron = require('node-cron');

function updateStatus(dbConn, callback) {
  // Get the current date
  const currentDate = new Date();
  // Select all events from the 'events' table where the start date is before the current date and the end date is after the current date
  dbConn.query(
    'SELECT * FROM practiceme.events WHERE eventStart < ? AND eventEnd > ?',
    [currentDate, currentDate],
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) return callback(error, null);

      // For each row in the results, update the status of the event to 'ongoing'
      results.forEach((row) => {
        dbConn.query(
          'UPDATE practiceme.events SET status = "ongoing" WHERE eventId = ?',
          [row.id],
          (error) => {
            if (error) return callback(error, null);
          }
        );
      });
    }
  );
}

function updateStatus2(dbConn, callback) {
  // Get the current date
  const currentDate = new Date();
  // Select all events from the 'events' table where the end date is before the current date
  dbConn.query(
    'SELECT * FROM practiceme.events WHERE eventEnd < ?',
    [currentDate],
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) return callback(error, null);

      // For each row in the results, update the status of the event to 'past'
      results.forEach((row) => {
        dbConn.query(
          'UPDATE practiceme.events SET status = "past" WHERE eventId = ?',
          [row.id],
          (error) => {
            if (error) return callback(error, null);
          }
        );
      });
    }
  );
}

// Run the 'updateStatus' function every minute using the cron library
cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  console.log('Updating status column every minute.');
  var dbConn = db.getConnection();
  dbConn.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    updateStatus(dbConn, (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error updating status column:', error);
      } else {
        console.log('Status column updated successfully.');
      }
      updateStatus2(dbConn, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('Error updating status column:', error);
        } else {
          console.log('Status column updated successfully.');
        }
        // Close the connection to the database
        dbConn.end();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: @Ipizzinidev No more errors! However, why is my database status column not changing?

Comment: Do let me know if you me to show you anything to help solve this problem!

Comment: Try to use `NOW()` instead of the JS Date as filter parameter: `SELECT * FROM practiceme.events WHERE eventEnd < NOW()` and `SELECT * FROM practiceme.events WHERE eventStart < NOW() AND eventEnd > NOW()`. If this doesn't work you will need to debug and check if the `SELECT`s are actually returning some values.